# SPFX Deployment Failed Correlation ID

Tags: reactjs, spfx

We have a pretty simply react based SPFX web part we are trying to deploy to the Apps for SharePoint catalog.

It does not work for my developer:
[image]

If I delete the app and then drag it back out it does work.  Smells like a permission issue but I have no idea where to even look to see what the actual error is.  I see plenty of references online about how on premise SP has logs you could view but there seems to be no equivalent for SharePoint Online.
I would love to hear some suggestions.  Note that I made my developer a site admin.  Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

So this might fall under the heading of developer being a bit dense.  I had added her as an admin for the SP site that she is adding her parts to but did not add her as an admin to the SP site used for the application catalog.  Once I did that the error went away.  It would be nice if the error would give some indication of what the actual cause was rather than me having to open a ticket with Microsoft support and inferring what the issue was.